# REST and blockingqueue

Tags: rest, asynchronous, jax-rs, swagger

I am going to keep it short, we have a product that uses BPM and internal queue with lots of EJBs  (pojo implementation). We decided to add REST to the product and we zeroed in to JAX-RS and Swagger for documentation. 
Now, we created endpoint pointing to a async scenario in a such a way that when REST request arrives we start the BPMN flow asynchronously and then we wait for agreed timeout duration for flows to finish so that we can parallelly send a response to internal queue, which receive message when BPMN flow finished processing and then can construct REST response.

I am looking for some enterprise pattern or some utility framework to help me achieve this and not invent it myself. I know Camel has lots of such patterns but I am not so sure I am looking for something available on JDK 1.6 compatible framework to simulate this synchronous behavior.

I would have something like a RxJava or some observer notifier pattern probably no internal JMS queues to pass message between threads. A concurrent and thread-safe soilutuion is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> I would have something like a RxJava or some observer notifier pattern probably no internal JMS queues to pass message between threads. A concurrent and thread-safe solution is what I am looking for.

If you are to be using JAX-RS, then you should probably become familiar with the [Asynchronous Server API](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html#d0e10297).  For a slow but synchronous operation, you would simply [dispatch a task to your executor](http://allegro.tech/2014/10/async-rest.html), and resume the suspended request when you have a result.

Another approach is to store the suspended request in a shared data structure, with a worker responsible for observing the completed flows, looking up the suspended request and dispatching the response.

The [ResponseServlet](https://github.com/mikeb01/ticketing/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lmax/ticketing/web/ResponseServlet.java#L185) from Michael Barker's ticketing demonstration shows this basic idea (Barker's code uses servlets rather than JAX-RS, and [Disruptor](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor) rather than RxJava, so you'll need to translate).

Additional resources on async response processing

- https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-2rd-edition/content/en/part1/chapter13/server_asynchronous_response_processing.html
- http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2014/12/asynchronous-timeouts-with.html